# MVC 4 - How to handle objects with time series

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I feel this is kind of a very beginner question, but I am a beginner..:

The entity "Stock" represents a stock and I am looking for a good way to save each stock's price-day data. The price-day data contains an additional field for the user who added the price.

I considered using a) a dictionary b) a special class "price" where each stock would reference a list of prices or c) an array. My goal is to have an easy way to later on create a chart for a stock and to do simple calculations (price change from day0 to day1, for example).

Each day, one new price is added for a stock.

**Question: What would be a good way to store the price-day-user data?** 
I feel a price-class is not optimal and a dictionary is meant for key-value. Thank you for your input and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your already defined your "price" as a pair of Value and Day therefore I would go for class. This should be best practice since you may also enhance it with new properties in the future.

```
List<Price> Stock.PricesPerDay
```